# How can I enable ufw automatically on boot?

Tags: startup, ufw

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Firewall is active and enabled on system startup

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

But after I restart the system and run `sudo ufw status`, I get the message:

```
Status: inactive
```

How can I solve this problem?

By the way, my `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` does have `ENABLED=yes.`

Comment: Post output of this command:
`sudo service ufw start`

Answer (score 30):

It would've been very useful if you had mention at least what the distribution is or the version of the package that you are using.

However if you are running systemd try this:

```
sudo systemctl enable ufw
```

This should enable the autostart of the service in init.d. Please be sure to enable and test the service configuration beforehand, so you don't fail at booting the system the next time

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 6):

For me, this was a conflict with `firewalld`, and was resolved with `sudo systemctl disable firewalld`

Comment: A big thank you to you! I was fighting with this problem on a suse box and your answer helped me

Comment: same as the comment above, using Oracle cloud Ubuntu instances

Answer (score 4):

You could add the enable command to your rc.local script which runs on startup.

```
For Debian, it's located in /etc/rc.local
For Ubuntu, it's also located in /etc/rc.local
For Fedora, it's located in /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Add your command to the top of `exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ufw allow ***
sudo ufw enable
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

(just in case you have other firewall managers enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, this solution worked for me:

https://devtidbits.com/2019/07/31/ufw-service-not-loading-after-a-reboot/

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight modification from the answer @peterh gave, for those if you don't already have the `rc.local` in those folders (`/etc/` or `/etc/rc.d/`), like in Archlinux, you'll have to create your own. I did that slight bit of modification as follows:

(This is done in a systemd OS)

create a text file `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` using whatever tool you like, I'm using vim so it'll be:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

And then add:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable /etc/rc.local


[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that, run:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

It'll create a symlink to run the service on startup (according to one person on Archlinux forum, you don't need this command to enable it because if the file exists, the system will automatically enable it, but just in case.)

And finally you can add the `rc.local` script to `/etc/` directory. You can read about it online and create a file of your prefrence but for the sake of simplicity I'll just use this:

`sudo vim /etc/rc.local`

```
# rc.local file
#!/bin/sh

# Enable firewall (sudo command)

ufw enable

# Must always be the last line
exit 0
```

Mark it as executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

You can check if the file is correct and is working without having to reboot by `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` and then see its status `sudo systemctl status rc-local.service` if there's any indicator that the script was shutdown `inactive` that means the proccess was successfully executed

FYI: Now you can add any command using sudo to run on startup in `rc.local` , just be careful

Again this answer may be excessive but I just want to elaborate a bit more from above, you may have resolved your question by now but I'm adding this for anyone who just happen to stumble across this site and still don't know what to do.

That's it, have a great day!